# Test if conditional formatting is TRUE VBA and highlight entire row

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to determine whether or not a specific cell returns a TRUE value from conditional formatting, and then highlighting the entire row (or even just one cell) if it does return true. The conditional formatting is in column B, and would like it highlight the entire row.

I am ultimately trying to add up numbers in column F if the conditional formatting returned TRUE in column B, but I can figure out that part if I can simply determine if the conditional formatting returned true or not. I have searched every forum, site, example, etc. I could find and still have not been able to make it work.

I am running conditional formatting to search a large amount of data for multiple different instances. The only way I could figure out how to do it was to run each condition as a separate conditional format. Here is a portion of one of the subs (each sub has about 30 conditional formats and there are about 10 subs):

```
 Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
"=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Acadia Realty Trust "",B1))"
 Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
 .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
.Color = 65535
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
"=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Aimco "",B1))"
 Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
 .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
.Color = 65535
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
"=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Alexandria Real Estate Equities, Inc"",B1))"
 Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
 .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
.Color = 65535
.TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

I only say that to say that I can't simply check the same test with conditional formatting, because there almost 300 different tests.

**UPDATE:**

I tried what Jeep suggested, and then what I commented below building multiple subs, each with an array in order to fit all 264 conditions, but when I did so *it only highlighted the last array, not all of the conditions* that were met in the first subs. I used the same code as @Jeeped suggested below, but put 24 conditions in the array, and I can that code into 11 subs, and my primary code looks as follows:

```
Public Sub REIT()
range("B:B").Select
Call A25
Call B25
Call C25
Call D25
Call E25
Call F25
Call G25
Call H25
Call I25
Call J25
Call K25
End Sub
```

I ended up just using two help columns to re-search the criteria and sum the data I needed, but I still have a problem with the highlighting.

Comment: How about using a separate check column (which you can hide if you like), containing a UDF in which you check all the various conditions, and if true return 1 into the cell, otherwise 0. Then with the conditional formatting, you just have to check whether the check column is 1.

Comment: You can use CF directly to color the whole row. You can use conditional logic to sum values with formulas. Any particular reason you want this done in VBA? Judging from your code you are not very experienced with VBA. If you want VBA to do the coloring, then you don't need Conditional Formatting. Use one OR the other, not both.

Comment: @ChrisMelville, I don't know enough about vba to make a UDF that is long enough to check all of the conditions.

Comment: @teylyn No, I am not very experienced. Using Jeeped's code below, VBA highlighted the entire row, but it is still conditionally formatted. So you recommend just using sumif and using an array for the criteria? I would love to know how to get VBA to highlight the row without CF, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @ChrisMelville I actually ended up using what you suggested by naming the criteria I'm searching to shorten the formula and then sumif true... Very simple, I don't know I over-complicated it. Cheers mate.

Comment: You're welcome. I generally find that there's more than one way to skin a cat in this type of situation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an array and use a loop. A [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) can handle the reference to the [Application.Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx) property.

```
Option Explicit

Sub makeThreeCFrules()
    Dim v As Long, vCFRs As Variant

    vCFRs = Array("=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Acadia Realty Trust "", $B1))", vbYellow, _
                  "=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Aimco "", $B1))", vbYellow, _
                  "=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Alexandria Real Estate Equities, Inc"", $B1))", vbYellow)
    With Selection.EntireRow
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        For v = LBound(vCFRs) To UBound(vCFRs) Step 2
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=vCFRs(v))
                .Interior.Color = vCFRs(v + 1)
            End With
        Next v
    End With
End Sub
```

The problem with your formulas was that you needed to anchor the column with `$B1`.

**[Alternate:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119970/countifs-with-range-criteria-on-different-sheets/27122367#27122367)**

If you can put a list of the search terms somewhere else in the workbook, you could accomplish this with a single 'reverse wildcard lookup'.

[image]
                    <sup>Search terms in Sheet6!A2:A4</sup>

```
Option Explicit

Sub makeAllCFrules()
    Dim v As Long, vCFRs As Variant

    With Selection.EntireRow
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
                Formula1:="=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(""*""&Sheet6!$A$2:$A$4&""*"",$B1, 0)))")
            .Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

It is critically important that no blank rows be included in the search terms range. If there are, you will be searching for a double wildcard and that will include everything. Of course, the supplied sub procedure could be modified to find the address of the search terms if they are subject to change.

[image: reverse_wildcard_results]
                    <sup>With Conditional Formatting Rule applied after selecting B1:B99</sup>

Comment: It is telling me that I have too many line continuations in the array. There are 275 conditions, so do I just have to build multiple arrays? or run like 10 different subs and call them into a public sub?

Comment: I tried to do run the multiple arrays but it did not highlight all of them. It looks as if when I did what I mentioned above it only highlighted the last array of option, not all of them. Any idea why?

Comment: I figured it out. Just needed to delete the .FormatConditions.Delete line, but then that leave the conditional formatting in the rest of the rows that are not true. Any idea how to edit the code so it only deletes untrue formats after all of the arrays have been run? Thanks Jeeped!

Comment: I don't think I am grasping just what you are trying to do. If there was a list of these search terms somewhere else in the workbook (e.g. Sheet6!A:A) you could accomplish this with a single conditional formatting rule. I've posted the alternate method above.

Comment: no I think you have it. I may be over-complicating my problem. I ended up doing something every similar to what you just suggested. You just did it in a more concise way than I managed to. Thank you for all your help!